# submit an issue to jira using custom contact form

Tags: jira

Can I submit an issue to Jira by using my custom contact form ?

On the submit button of my contact form I want to send an email to the support team as well as raise an issue to my Jira account.

Comment: Configure JIRA to accept issues via email.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at:
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/
(especially https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e1196)

You'll need some program/script to use the API but should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured JIRA to accept issues via email.